# Lexicalmente, o que acontece quando retornamos uma variável dentro de um método que está declarada na função desse método?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Alguém me ajuda a entender o contexto de execução desse código?

1. myVar é declarada no Global;
2. myVar é declarada em a();
3. b() é executado e myVar é declarada em b();
4. myVar não é encontrada em c():

dúvida: ele não deveria descer para procurar no b() ou no global? e trazer algum dos dois?

```js
function b () {
        function c() {
            console.log(myVar);
        }
        c();
        var myVar = 3
    }
function a() {
     b();
     var myVar = 2;
}

let myVar = 1

a();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada função cria o seu escopo. O `var` quando declarado/usado dentro de uma função declara essa variável e bloqueia acesso a variáveis com o mesmo nome fora desse escopo. Contudo, nas linhas anteriores à linha onde esse `var` é usado, o valor da variável ainda não está definida...

O JavaScript consegue usar funções declaradas antes de correr o código mas variáveis são usadas somente quando o código chega à linha onde estão. Isto chama-se *Hoisting*  e a diferença é:

```
function add() {} // function declaration - disponível em todo o escopo

var add = function () {} // function expression - declarada em todo o escopo,
                         // mas só disponível depois da linha ter sido corrida
```

Repara no exemplo:

```js
function a() {
  b();
  console.log(1, foo, typeof foo); // 1 undefined undefined
  var foo = 'bar';
  console.log(2, foo, typeof foo); // 2 bar string
  try {
    console.log(3, inexistente, typeof inexistente); // dá erro

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(4, err.message); // 4 inexistente is not defined
  }

  function b() {
    console.log(5, foo); // 5 undefined - a função corre mas a variável não
  }
}

a();
```

No caso da variável com o nome `inexistente` o código sabe que, ainda que não tenha sido declarada nas linhas que estão a ser executadas, essa variável nunca é declarada. Daí o erro.

> **Nota:** *contexto de execução* refere-se ao `this`, a tua pergunta refere-se a *Hoisting* e escopo de variáveis.